# Exceptions in Java (Recoverable vs Fatal)

Tags: java, exception

I have a java program that tries to collect a certain rss feed from a list of servers.  If there are any failures, (authentication, connection, etc) I want to throw an exception that basically takes me back to the main loop where I can catch it, display some info in the logs, and then move on the trying the next server in the loop.   Most exceptions seem to be fatal though... even when they don't really need to be.  I beleive I have seen exceptions that are not fatal... but don't remember for sure.  I have tried to search around but I am probably using the wrong terminology.

Can someone help me get pointed in the right direction here?  Are there particular types of exceptions I can throw that will be recoverable vs stopping the entire program in its tracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the type of the exception you throw, it will go up the call stack until it's caught. So you just need to catch it:

```
for (Server server : servers) {
    try {
        contactServer(server);
    }
    catch (MyCustomException e) {
        System.out.println("problem in contacting this server. Let's continue with the other ones");
    }
}
```

Read the [Java tutorial about exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 2):

Error:

> An Error "indicates serious problems that a reasonable application
> should not try to catch."

Exception:

> An Exception "indicates conditions that a reasonable application might
> want to catch."

Exceptions are always meant to be recoverable, no matter checked or unchecked though it is possible always not to handle them, but it should be. while On the
other hand, error must be fatal. However, even error can be handled, but it would rather be just fancy way to say **"it's a crash"**

probably you would wanna have a look at [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) vs [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)

Comment: Simply linking isn't a good idea. I'd include important details in your post.

Answer (score 2):

No [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) needs to be fatal.  ([`Error`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) however, are meant to be fatal.  Don't catch them.)  All you have to do is catch the `Exception` somewhere, and it's not fatal.

```
try
{
    riskyMethod();
}
catch (ReallyScaryApparentlyFatalException e)
{
    log(e);
    // It's not fatal!
}
```

Comment: Can a subclass of error be *hypothetically* caught? And better yet, if an error is encountered in a classloader, how is the class use to dispatch the error as a throwable loaded?

Comment: anything *can* be caught `catch(Throwable t)`

Comment: Anything `Throwable` can be caught.

Answer (score 2):

There are no "unrecoverable exceptions" per se.  In Java, if it registers as an "exception" you can catch it:

```
try {
  // Attempt to open a server port
} catch (SecurityException ex) {
  // You must not be able to open the port
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // Something else terrible happened.
} catch (Throwable th) {
  // Something *really* terrible happened.
}
```

What you may want, if you are creating a server connecting application, something like this:

```
for(Server server : servers) {
  try {
    // server.connectToTheServer();
    // Do stuff with the connection
  } catch (Throwable th) {
    //Log the error and move along.
  }
}
```